# Получение транскрипции слова в соответствии с правилами русского языка

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Разработать данную программу задали на 3 курсе по дисциплине "Обработка естественного языка".

Сначала на вход должен подаваться файл со списком слов (около 200), в которых уже расставлено ударение. Затем вводится слово из заданного списка или любое другое. И нужно чтобы программа выдала его транскрипцию.

Подскажите хотя бы один цикл для обработки слова и проверки его на правила транскрипции.
Язык - С++, Среда: Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: О какой транскрипции идет речь? Фонетической, обычной транслитерации? Какой-то другой? На каком языке слова? Может вы еще и конкретный алгоритм укажете, который надо использовать?

Comment: именно фонетической, слова на русском языке - правила транскрипции же русского языка надо использовать.
Алгоритма нам не дали, это я хотела спросить здесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу особой проблемы. Для начала нужно определить правила преобразования. А дальше уже плясать от них. В самом простом варианте, где возможны лишь варианты "x" -> "y" и "z" -> "ab" можно просто идти по строке слева направо и заменять все подходящие комбинации символов. Если же необходим анализ более сложный (например, зависимость фонетики от закрытости слога), то можно придумать более сложный алгоритм. Но опять же для реализации нужно для начала иметь и представлять этот самый алгоритм. А на каком языке его реализовывать - это уже технический вопрос.

В качестве хороших инструментов могу предложить библиотеку boost::regex и алгоритм std::replace. В стандартном C я бы отослал изучать `<string.h>`.

Необходимые сведения именно по фонетике русского языка, вероятно, имеет смысл взять из Википедии: [русский язык](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA#.D0.A4.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.B8_.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) и [русская фонетика](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю хотя бы библиотеки, а то нам задали задание, а как реализовать не объяснили

Comment: "можно просто идти по строке слева направо" - подскажете какой функцией, а то мы такого не проходили

Comment: <pre>char x[1024]; // Ваша строка
char *p = &x; // указатель на Вашу строку
for (char *i = p; *i != 0; i++)
// идем по строке слева направо, пока не встретится символ с кодом 0
{
   switch (*i) {case 'а': ....; case 'b': ...}
   // смотрим какой у нас сммвол и в зависимости от этого делаем разные вещи.
}</pre>

Comment: Замечу, что "плясать" нужно начинать от конкретных фонетических систем. Насколько мне известно, их несколько, и они сложны: нет простого отображения букв слова на фонемы, но нужно анализировать позицию букв, их соседей, и прочее. В зависимости от позиции буквы в слове, ее соседних букв и других условий, ей могут соответствовать одна или две фонемы. Короче, надо идти в библиотеку и искать соответствующую литературу по фонетике русского языка. А потом уже думать, как выразить правила транскрипции на C++.

Comment: <i>В зависимости от позиции буквы в слове, ее соседних букв и других условий, ей могут соответствовать одна или две фонемы</i>

Или 0 фонем. Как в случае с мягким знаком, который может означать лишь мягкость предыдущей согласной.

<i>Насколько мне известно, их несколько, и они сложны:</i>

Согласен. Но русский язык не самый сложный, если подумать. Английский с их закрытыми-открытыми слогами будет в реализации существенно неприятнее. Тем более, что мы специалистами по лингвистике (фонетике) не являемся. А именно они и должны описывать набор правил для описания фонетической системы =(

Comment: Таким образом, на основе обсуждения выяснилось, что данная задача разбивается на 2 маленьких этапа.

1) Разработка языка (системы обозначений), описывающего преобразование произвольных последовательностей символов кириллицы в фонемы русского языка.

2) Написание интерпретатора (компилятора) данного языка, получающего подсказки по ударениям из задаваемого пользователем файла.

Comment: Поддерживаю. п.1 - это по сути и есть изменяемая часть алгоритма. Которая для разных языковых систем будет разная. И задается ТС. А п.2 - это постоянная часть. Т.е. то, что реализует работу с файлами, ввод-вывод и основная часть алгоритма преобразования (без правил). Причем могу отметить, что С++ судя по всему является не самым оптимальным средством для реализации таких программных продуктов.

Comment: Спасибо, нам на этом предмете как раз только про фонетику и рассказывают, мне неясна сама реализация, но буду пробовать

Comment: Спасибо за цикл, но у меня выдает ошибку на строку char *p = &x;
error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать 'char (*)[1024]' в 'char *'

Comment: Там опечатка. Название массива по сути и есть указатель на его начало. Т.е. верно будет так: `char *p = x;` или `char *p = &x[0];`